# how to write data to a window opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am wondering how to write data stored in a float to a window or an image in opencv.
Initially I tried using puttext:

```
distance1 = (image_size * focal_length)/num_pix1
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(imgFile,distance1,(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

However, since the data stored is not a string, this doesn't work. Is there perhaps an easier way to write float data to a window perhaps in a similar way to how I can put trackbars in a window

Comment: could you not use a `stringstream` and pass this to `putText`?

Comment: You could try something like `cv2.putText(imgFile, "{:.2f}".format(distance1), ...)`

Comment: Thanks martin I think thats sorted it

Answer (score 1):

As you have seen `cv2.putText` takes a text argument, so you need to first convert any numeric values into text.

For floating point numbers this can be easily done using [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=format%20mini#format-specification-mini-language) as follows:

```
cv2.putText(imgFile, f"{distance1:.2f}", (10, 500), font, 4,(255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

The `.2f` specifies 2 decimal places should be used to format the float.